# How to choose the size the icon launcher?

Tags: android

Once you have installed your app in a device, it appears   with a specific size, the same size of Facebook app.  I want to know how to make it bigger, there are many apps with a bigger icon launcher than Facebook's.

Snapchat is a good example, and that's the size that I'm looking for.

Comment: Default Android icons have **padding** in them, just removing the padding and magnify the image to fit all corners will do the job!

Answer (score 0):

Just delete all the ic_launcher.png in the resources/drawable folder (all drawables folder), then add your logo (of the size which you want it to be) and paste it into only drawable folder. This way your icon would appear bigger/smaller depending on the size of your image.